# Loading data on component load

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

One would think this is an easy task. But how do I call a service method on component load without it firing twice?

Currently -

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   await Initialize(); 
}

private async Task Initialize()
{
    Video = await _VideoService.GetAsync(Id);
}
```

Right now this gets called twice, which doens't seem like a good idea to hit the database twice for the same information.

I've tried just having this below, but it will throw an error before it even renders everytime.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if(firstRender)
  { 
    await Initialize();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`OnInitializedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-initialization-methods) lifecycle method for initializing the component is executed **twice**:

1. When the component is prerendered statically.
2. After the server connection has been established.

It is by design - check [Stateful reconnection after prerendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering) and other sections of this article to figure out what would be the safe way to load data in your case. Maybe it is [`SetParametersAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#before-parameters-are-set) or [`OnParametersSetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-parameters-are-set)