# Blazor Webassembly Configuration (appsettings.json) Loading null values in Component Initially

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WebAssembly App Loads Configuration Values After Executing Methods Resulting in Null's Initialy then it will return with correct values.

I followed [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Appseting File:

```
wwwroot/appsettings.json
```

My Component.razor:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Configuration example</h1>

<p>Message: @Configuration["message"]</p>
@code {
   protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
   {
      await trying to read Configuration["Message"];
    }
}
```

My Program.cs File:

```
 public class Program
        {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

My _Imports.razor

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IConfiguration Configuration;
```

Note: *Understand that I am getting the value's correctly but always null first then re-renders with correct values, i am using OnParametersSetAsync() as entry point, i understand OnParametersSetAsync() changes on every Parameter Change. but the Configuration Values should be constant not null first right?*

Comment: Please provide a simple reproduction of the issue - preferably in a GH repo or similar. You haven't said where you are seeing a null either. From your provided code, there would only be one render, so when you say it re-renders - you are doing something other than shown here. What exactly is this: "await trying to read Configuration["Message"];"?

Comment: Some of those override methods are called twice, check for null first and see if it's called again with the correct data.

Comment: @PawBaltzersen yep that's  pretty much what's happening

Comment: @smj As far as I know this is intended behaviour. It might be subject to change, but I don't know. The null check is your best option for now.

Comment: It worked for me on a new project i am not sure exactly but updating nugat packages to latest release did it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today when I tried to fetch connection string value from appsettings.json. Try to **Restart Visual Studio** and it will work properly.

Comment: Buddy it's Blazor WebAssembly Runtime Issue, Configuration Works Just fine after it get null first's then it will re-render with correct value

Answer (score 0):

The component is instantiated twice, before and after loading data. This is per design to show the page faster and then load the data after.

[Why does Blazor renders component twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981661/why-does-blazor-renders-component-twice)

[Why are Blazor lifecycle methods getting executed twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075628/why-are-blazor-lifecycle-methods-getting-executed-twice)

[Loading data on component load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401430/loading-data-on-component-load)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering

Answer (score 0):

it worked after updating to blazor nuget packages from 3.2.0 to 3.2.1